# Entity Framework Core not loading 1 to 0 foreign key entity

Tags: asp.net-core, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I have three simple entities - a **Basket**, **Product** and **BasketItem**. 
So a Product is added to a Basket through a BasketItem. Each BasketItem **must** be connected to one Product & one Basket, however a Product **doesn't have to be** connected to a BasketItem (i.e. is not yet added to any baskets).

Basket & BasketItem have a 1-many relationship, while BasketItem & Product have a 1-0 relationship, meaning a Product can be in a Basket (through BasketItem), but doesn't have to be.

I've set up a DbContext in the regular way, and everything works fine except the Product entity is null when accessed through the BasketItem, ie entity framework does not load it at all. E.g.

basket.BasketItems.FirstOrDefault().Product gives null.

I've been googling for hours and couldn't find a solution. I've also tried several variations of:

```
builder.Entity<BasketItem>().HasOne(p => p.Product);
```

but none have worked. 
Code provided below:

```
public class Basket
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; } = new List<BasketItem>();
}
```

}

```
public class BasketItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public int BasketID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BasketID")]
    public virtual Basket Basket { get; set; }

    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

In my context set up:

```
     builder.Entity<Product>().HasData(new Product() { ID = 1, ProductName = "Harry Potter hardback collection", Description = "All 7 Harry Potter books in hardback.", Price = 150.00 });
```

...

```
builder.Entity<Basket>().HasData(new Basket() { ID = 1, BasketTotalPrice = 750 });

builder.Entity<BasketItem>().HasOne(p => p.Product);

builder.Entity<BasketItem>().HasData(new BasketItem() { ID = 1, BasketID = 1, ProductID = 1, ProductQuantity = 2 });
```

Comment: have you tried context.Basket.Include(b => b.BasketItems).ThenInclude(bi => bi.Product).FirstOrDefault().Product ?

Comment: @darem this is the one, it was ThenInclude that I was missing. Cheers mate. Leave a reply so I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention in the comment you have to `Include()` the BasketItmens first. `ThenInclude()` the Products.

So in your case the solutions is

```
context.Basket.Include(b => b.BasketItems).ThenInclude(bi => bi.Product).FirstOrDefault().Product
```

Answer (score 2):

[Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) doc's section.

You will have to use the `Include()` method

Comment: It was actually ThenInclude() that I was missing that Darem mentioned, but I found it on your link too, thanks